# Threads Possible Cause of Memory Leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, threadpool, thread-sleep, permgen

Hi can someone identify this threads ? are these the possible causes of memory leaks ? Cause im having a permgen out of memory error when redeploying webapps overtime. thanks in advance.

[image: Pool Threads]

[image: Thread Sleeps]

[image: C3P0 Pool Threads]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to identify PermGen memory leaks only given your thread screen shots. Please follow [these instructions on my blog](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/) to find any leaks. To prevent problems caused by ClassLoader leaks, add [my ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention) to your application.

Comment: HI i've tried adding your library . But on start up it shows this kind of logs .

`WARNING: Unable to construct RuntimeException without stack trace. The likely reason is that you are using Java <= 1.6. No worries, except there is one kind of leak you're not protected from (https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/issues/36). If you are already on Java 1.7+, please report issue to developer of this library!`

Is this fine or there's something wrong ?

Comment: BTW i'm currently using java 1.8

Comment: sorry for the confusion our server has the java version of 1.6.0_39-b04.

additional info:
i'm having "java.runtime.version=1.7.0_67-b01" that's indicated in my eclipse . but in my cmd im having java 1.8.0_20-b26

Comment: If you're on 1.6, just ignore the warning (or better yet, update your Java version :-) )

Comment: Thankss ! and also should i just ignore this error message ?

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable, boolean, boolean)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987)
 at se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ReplaceDOMNormalizerSerializerAbortException.constructRuntimeExceptionWithoutStackTrace(ReplaceDOMNormalizerSerializerAbortException.java:56)`

Comment: Yes, those are related

Comment: is there a way to hide the error message stated above ?

Comment: Yes - update Java! [Java 6 EOL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) was **2013**...

You could also choose to suppress warn level messages using [JUL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) config or supply your own custom [Logger](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/blob/master/classloader-leak-prevention/classloader-leak-prevention-core/src/main/java/se/jiderhamn/classloader/leak/prevention/Logger.java) implementation.